# How can I use a remote GPU for hardware accelerated 3D rendering?

Tags: opengl, 3d, xserver

I know how to use VirtualGL to remotely connect to a server and run OpenGL applications. VirtualGL allows the 2D elements of the graphic application to pass from the server machine to the client machine through the SSH connection, but intercepts the 3D elements and renders them on the server machine and then sends the images in the form of a stream to the client X Server.

But I want to be able to run graphics applications installed on the client machine in such a manner that the 2D elements are rendered locally, while the 3D commands are sent after encapsulation through a high speed network to the server where they are rendered, and the images in the form of a stream are then sent back. Is there an existing solution or a configuration of VirtualGL that works in this manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's impossible with VirtualGL. VirtualGL works by intercepting GLX calls, redirecting them to a another Xorg server, rendering frames using `GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object` extension, and sending compressed images over network to client.

VirtualGL does not solve the issue of sending GLX calls over network.

I tried "indirect rendering", but there are many problems:

- It's disabled by default, due to security issues,
- Performance is terrible,
- It doesn't provide `GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object` extension required by VirtualGL.